# How do I disable the PuTTY bell via a command line parameter?

Tags: command-line, ssh, putty

What parameters would you have to pass, in order to disable the PuTTY bell via the command line?

Answer (score 20):

In *PuTTY Configuration* (start PuTTY without any options or sesions), you have a session called *Default Settings*. Just change the setting under `Terminal -> Bell` to `Visual Bell (flash window)` and then go back to the Session part of *PuTTY Configuration* and save this as the new *Default Settings*.

After doing this, all future sessions will have this disabled by default.

Answer (score 4):

Open the PuTTy settings and you should find the options as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do exactly what you ask. I would disable the bell in PuTTY's settings menu and save as a session. Then you can set PuTTY's command line options to `-load sessionname`.

You can also create a custom termcap/terminfo entry which has `bel` undefined.

There's no command you can run at the host that would instruct PuTTY to ignore ^G (bell).

`stty` has `-imaxbel`, but that most likely does not do what you want.

Comment: If he logs onto a bash shell, for example, one other option is to type `set bell-type visual` (or none) in the shell to temporarily change the audible behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it - almost! PuTTY stores all it's settings in registry as reg keys. Go to settings, change BELL to whatever you like, find key in registry, export it and import onto anther computer. Job done.